# Maya - Center Object Pivot to Locator/Cluster

Tags: python-2.7, maya, maya-api

I'm trying to move the selected object pivot to the center of a selection of vertices.

I have gotten to the point where I have the `xform` defined, but can't seem to move the object (defined as `obj`) pivot to this point

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
print sel
obj = cmds.ls(*sel, o=True)
print obj

selVerts = cmds.ls(sl=True)
tempClstr = cmds.cluster()
pos = cmds.xform(tempClstr[1], q=True, ws=True, rp=True)
loc = cmds.spaceLocator()
cmds.move(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2])
cmds.delete(tempClstr)

piv = cmds.xform (loc[1], piv=True, q=True, ws=True)
print piv
cmds.xform( obj, ws=True, piv=(piv[0], piv[1], piv[2]) )
```

Here's what I've got, any extra eyes that can spot what im missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maya Python - Set object pivot to selection center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902493/maya-python-set-object-pivot-to-selection-center)

Answer (score 1):

Your `obj` needs to be the transform node, but instead it is an array where each element is the same shape.

Try this:

```
import pymel.core as pm
bigNum = 1.0e+9
sel = pm.ls(sl=True, flatten=True)
min = pm.dt.Point(bigNum,bigNum,bigNum)
max =  pm.dt.Point(-bigNum,-bigNum,-bigNum)

for v in sel:
    p = pm.pointPosition( v )
    if p.x < min.x:
        min.x = p.x
    elif p.x > max.x:
        max.x = p.x
    if p.y < min.y:
        min.y = p.y
    elif p.y > max.y:
        max.y = p.y     
    if p.z < min.z:
        min.z = p.z
    elif p.z > max.z:
        max.z = p.z    

center = (min+max)*0.5

obj =  pm.listRelatives(pm.listRelatives(sel[0], p=True), p=True)
pm.xform (obj, piv=(center.x, center.y, center.z) , ws=True)
pm.spaceLocator(p=center)

pm.select(obj)
```

The `flatten` flag of `ls` will make sure every vertex has an entry in the result array. Vertices with adjacent indices will not be grouped.

Rather than make a temporary cluster, it iterates to find the world space bounding box, and then calculates its center.

The call to `listRelatives` nested in another `listRelatives` gets the transform node associated with the first vertex. (It assumes all selected vertices are in the same mesh).