# Maya Python - Set object pivot to selection center

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I'm trying to move the selected object pivot to the center of the objects selected vertices.

When I run the code I don't recieve any errors and almost everything works as intended, However the pivot of (obj)my selected object doesn't seem to set itself to the locator xform(piv).

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
print sel
obj = cmds.ls(*sel, o=True)
print obj

selVerts = cmds.ls(sl=True)
tempClstr = cmds.cluster()
pos = cmds.xform(tempClstr[1], q=True, ws=True, rp=True)
loc = cmds.spaceLocator()
cmds.move(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2])
cmds.delete(tempClstr)

piv = cmds.xform (loc[1], piv=True, q=True, ws=True)
print piv
cmds.xform( obj, ws=True, piv=(piv[0], piv[1], piv[2]) )
```

Need some help on this one fast.
Any extra eyes that can spot what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue was that when you were using `obj = cmds.ls(*sel, o=True)`, it was only capturing the object's shape node instead of its transform. You can use `cmds.listRelatives` to get the shape's transform. You also don't need to create the locator as the cluster already gives you the position.

This seems to work for me, though you may want to consider some additional error checking for the selection portion as it assumes a lot.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
shapes = cmds.ls(sel, o=True)
obj = cmds.listRelatives(shapes[0], f=True, parent=True)[0]

selVerts = cmds.ls(sl=True)
tempClstr = cmds.cluster()
piv = cmds.xform(tempClstr[1], q=True, ws=True, rp=True)
cmds.delete(tempClstr)

cmds.xform(obj, ws=True, piv=(piv[0], piv[1], piv[2]) )
```